# Do hotfixes that span multiple product versions need to be reinstalled if a newer version is installed later?

Tags: windows-xp, updates, hotfix

Microsoft has a hotfix for [KB2964358](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2964358) as further described in [MS14-021](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/SecurityBulletins/2014/ms14-021?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

This security update is for the following systems:

- Systems that are running Internet Explorer versions 6 through 10.
- Systems that are running Internet Explorer 11 and have security
  update 2929437 or 2919355 installed.

If I install this hotfix with some version of Internet Explorer (such as version 6) and then later install a newer version (such as 7 or 8), do I need to install this hotfix again?

Comment: Are you aware you are comparing Windows XP updates to Windows 7 updates? The latest version of Internet Explorer that Windows XP supported was Internet Explorer 8

Comment: "do I need to install this hotfix again?" Let Windows updates figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

> If I install this hotfix with some version of Internet Explorer (such as version 6) and then later install a newer version (such as 7 or 8), do I need to install this hotfix again?

Newer versions of Internet Explorer always contained the fixes from previous updates. You can confirm that is the case by looking and comparing the [File Information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2-april-8-2014-1ab5e1aa-c33c-cc1e-5d93-a6c2f0bf82d3) of an earlier update to that of a newer security update.  Internet Explorer 7 contains all the fixes for Internet Explore 6, any security issues that were found in both Internet Explorer 6 and Internet Explorer 7 were typically released as separate updates.

If the file version of a specific component is higher than that listed in an older update, and yet you have the newer update installed, you can rest assured the fixes in the earlier update are included.

You cannot of course compare [KB2929437](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2-april-8-2014-1ab5e1aa-c33c-cc1e-5d93-a6c2f0bf82d3) a Internet Explorer 11 update to that of [KB2919355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-rt-8-1-windows-8-1-and-windows-server-2012-r2-update-april-2014-3c9d820b-7079-359d-8660-21de648fa31d) which is a Windows 8.1 update.  In order to verify a newer Internet Explorer 11 update includes the fixes of a previous Internet Explorer update you might compare two Internet Explorer 11 updates.

> Microsoft has a hotfix for KB2964358 as further described in MS14-021.

Every update to Internet Explorer, released after May 1 2014, contains the fix to address MS14-021.  This would be the reason that, despite Windows 10 having Internet Explorer 11 installed, it is not listed in the security bulletin.  That would because the bulletin is not applicable to the the build of IE11 contained on every version Windows 10.